# IPhone regarding HTML content in UITableVIew

Tags: iphone

I want to render the HTML content in the UIlabel/UITableView Cell in iPhone.

After a quite research got to understand we can use the NSAttributedStrings:initWithHTML to acheive this rather then using UIWebView.

But couldnt get sample code how to acheive this.

Can any one provide sample code ,which can be used in the UITable view cell for the html content.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`NSAttributedString`'s `initWithHTML:` method is only available on Mac OS X.

Comment: Thank you for the response Jack.So do we have any other way to render the HTML content to the UITableViewCell/UILabel